# Stuck in an infinite loop reading from stdin (C)

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, infinite

my program keeps seg faulting and using gdb it runs until it gets into an infinite while loop. I cant figure out why it would do this, can someone help me?

```
char tmpstring[1024];
    char* fileName;
    off_t size;
    char* pos;
    char *token;
    int total = 0;
    char* kiloCheck;
    char* tstallCheck;
    char* tmomCheck;

while (fgets(tmpstring, 1024, stdin)) 
    {
        fileName = tmpstring;
        //remove newline
        if ((pos=strchr(fileName, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';

        token = strtok(fileName, s);

        //walk through tokens
        while(token != NULL){

            size = filesize(token);
            total += size;

            token = strtok(NULL, s);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I guess you are invoking in gdb via "run < input.txt"

Comment: nope, I run echo"filename1 filename2 filename3" | ./myprogram

Comment: so "s" is contains a space char ?

Comment: @Gravity I am guessing we are only seeing the snipplet he suspect being the cause of the segfault

Comment: btw @FullCombatBeard I was mentionning how you run you code in GDB, if you only use run, no wonder it is stuck waiting for input

Comment: the 'while( fgest(...' line with exit that loop when stdin is empty or a I/O error occurs.  so that is not the problem.  the 'while(token...' loop will only exit when the 'end' of fileName is reached.  That occurs when strtok() does not find any of the 'delimiters' (in this case the contents of 's' or a trailing '\0') in the input.  So there are two things to look at: 1) the contents of 's'  2) the contents of fileName  Starting with: where the trailing '\0' is located in both of the above strings

Comment: sorry s was defined a little earlier as char s[2] = " ";

Comment: @FullCombatBeard of course next suspect would be filesize, but I really would be interested to see how you would run it through GDB

Comment: you are doing something to your token with filesize, that is the only explanation, because the second while loop can only run so many times if the token remains unchanged

Comment: in any case, I don't see how you cannot see what is going on with a debugger

Comment: Does `filesize()` use `strtok()`?  If so, that is a problem.

Comment: Consider using `strtok_r` or `strsep` if your system supports them.